# I am getting this errror when trying to install the newest version of Python 3. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Tags: python, error-handling

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for python3.7... no
checking for python3... python3
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for --with-icc... no
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/tylmorse/Downloads/Python-3.7.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

This question is different from the other in that I am trying to install the 64bit version as opposed to the 32bit. Also, below are the contents of config.log.

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by python configure 3.7, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

$ ./configure 
## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = MintCondition
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 4.15.0-20-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /snap/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2802: checking build system type
configure:2816: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2836: checking host system type
configure:2849: result: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure:2879: checking for python3.7
configure:2909: result: no
configure:2879: checking for python3
configure:2895: found /usr/bin/python3
configure:2906: result: python3
configure:3000: checking for --enable-universalsdk
configure:3047: result: no
configure:3070: checking for --with-universal-archs
configure:3085: result: no
configure:3241: checking MACHDEP
configure:3447: checking for --without-gcc
configure:3470: result: no
configure:3473: checking for --with-icc
configure:3493: result: no
configure:3617: checking for gcc
configure:3633: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:3644: result: gcc
configure:3873: checking for C compiler version
configure:3882: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3893: $? = 0
configure:3882: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-as=/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-as --with-ld=/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 
configure:3893: $? = 0
configure:3882: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3893: $? = 1
configure:3882: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3893: $? = 1
configure:3913: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3935: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find Scrt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3939: $? = 1
configure:3977: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define _GNU_SOURCE 1
| #define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
| #define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
| #define _DARWIN_C_SOURCE 1
| #define _PYTHONFRAMEWORK ""
| #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
| #define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1
| #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3982: error: in `/home/tylmorse/Downloads/Python-3.7.0':
configure:3984: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_MACHDEP_set=
ac_cv_env_MACHDEP_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ac_cv_prog_PYTHON_FOR_REGEN=python3
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ABIFLAGS=''
AR=''
ARCH_RUN_32BIT=''
ARFLAGS=''
BASECFLAGS=''
BASECPPFLAGS=''
BLDLIBRARY=''
BLDSHARED=''
BUILDEXEEXT=''
CC='gcc'
CCSHARED=''
CFLAGS=''
CFLAGSFORSHARED=''
CFLAGS_ALIASING=''
CFLAGS_NODIST=''
CONFIGURE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=''
CONFIG_ARGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
DEFS=''
DEF_MAKE_ALL_RULE=''
DEF_MAKE_RULE=''
DFLAGS=''
DLINCLDIR=''
DLLLIBRARY=''
DTRACE=''
DTRACE_HEADERS=''
DTRACE_OBJS=''
DYNLOADFILE=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENSUREPIP=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPORT_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='#'
EXT_SUFFIX=''
FRAMEWORKALTINSTALLFIRST=''
FRAMEWORKALTINSTALLLAST=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLAPPSPREFIX=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLFIRST=''
FRAMEWORKINSTALLLAST=''
FRAMEWORKPYTHONW=''
FRAMEWORKUNIXTOOLSPREFIX='/usr/local'
GITBRANCH=''
GITTAG=''
GITVERSION=''
GNULD=''
GREP=''
HAS_GIT='no-repository'
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_3_ARG=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_5_ARG=''
HAVE_GETHOSTBYNAME_R_6_ARG=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
INSTSONAME=''
LDCXXSHARED=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDLAST=''
LDLIBRARY=''
LDLIBRARYDIR=''
LDSHARED=''
LDVERSION=''
LIBC=''
LIBFFI_INCLUDEDIR=''
LIBM=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBPL=''
LIBRARY=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL_CRUFT=''
LINKCC=''
LINKFORSHARED=''
LIPO_32BIT_FLAGS=''
LLVM_PROFDATA=''
LLVM_PROF_ERR=''
LLVM_PROF_FILE=''
LLVM_PROF_FOUND=''
LLVM_PROF_MERGER=''
LN=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MACHDEP='linux'
MACHDEP_OBJS=''
MAINCC=''
MKDIR_P=''
MULTIARCH=''
MULTIARCH_CPPFLAGS=''
NO_AS_NEEDED=''
OBJEXT=''
OPENSSL_INCLUDES=''
OPENSSL_LDFLAGS=''
OPENSSL_LIBS=''
OPT=''
OTHER_LIBTOOL_OPT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='https://bugs.python.org/'
PACKAGE_NAME='python'
PACKAGE_STRING='python 3.7'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='python'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='3.7'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PGO_PROF_GEN_FLAG=''
PGO_PROF_USE_FLAG=''
PKG_CONFIG=''
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=''
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=''
PLATFORM_TRIPLET=''
PY3LIBRARY=''
PYTHONFRAMEWORK=''
PYTHONFRAMEWORKDIR='no-framework'
PYTHONFRAMEWORKIDENTIFIER='org.python.python'
PYTHONFRAMEWORKINSTALLDIR=''
PYTHONFRAMEWORKPREFIX=''
PYTHON_FOR_BUILD='./$(BUILDPYTHON) -E'
PYTHON_FOR_REGEN='python3'
PY_ENABLE_SHARED=''
READELF=''
RUNSHARED=''
SED=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
SHLIBS=''
SHLIB_SUFFIX=''
SOABI=''
SOVERSION='1.0'
SRCDIRS=''
TCLTK_INCLUDES=''
TCLTK_LIBS=''
THREADHEADERS=''
TRUE=''
UNIVERSALSDK=''
UNIVERSAL_ARCH_FLAGS=''
VERSION='3.7'
_PYTHON_HOST_PLATFORM=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_READELF=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='pc'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='pc'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target=''
target_alias=''
target_cpu=''
target_os=''
target_vendor=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#define _NETBSD_SOURCE 1
#define __BSD_VISIBLE 1
#define _DARWIN_C_SOURCE 1
#define _PYTHONFRAMEWORK ""
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED 1
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: @garethTheRed The proposed duplicate is trying to use build system x86_64 on host system x86_32 and that's what broke the build... This one doesn't look the same, it's clearly listing x86_64-pc-linux-gnu as both build and host system types... So doesn't necessarily look like a duplicate.

Comment: @SpoopsForDays Can you please post the contents of `config.log` somewhere (a paste bin or something) and link it here? That might help troubleshoot your issue...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329887/compiling-problems-cannot-find-crt1-o

Comment: The files `Scrt1.o` and `crti.o` are missing. Your package manager should have installed them together with the C compiler, because the compiler won't produce executable without these files.